# Help solving a system of differential equations -- more variables than derivatives

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I need help solving this system of equations:

$\dot{x}_1=-3x_1-2x_2\\ \dot{x}_2=2x_2-x_3.$

I'm confused by the inclusion of $x_3$ since we don't have an equation for $\dot{x}_3$.  I'm not sure how to make the coefficient matrix for the system without an equation for $\dot{x}_3$.

Comment: You are right, I think there is a missing context.

Answer (score 2):

$x_3$ can be considered as an input function for the system

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
\dot x_1\\
\dot x_2
\end{array}
\right) = 
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
-3& -2\\
0 & 2
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x_1\\
x_2
\end{array}
\right)+
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
0\\
-1
\end{array}
\right) x_3
$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, but unfortunately I'm still not sure where to go from there.  I've never solved a system like this before...can you elaborate on what you mean by "x3 can be considered as an input function for the system", or what the next step would be?

Comment: The characterization of $x_3$ as input is associated with the control system concept. According to this paradigm, $x_3$ would serve to make the dynamic system of state variables $(x_1, x_2)$ reach and be maintained in some region of the phase plane $(x_1, x_2)$ with the proper action of $x_3$. This is possible depending on certain systematic characteristics.